# Not able to load a pickle file in azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, pickle

I want to load a pickle in Azure functions `__init__.py`. Pickle contains a model dumped in binary format. Model is written in below format

```
classifier = Pipeline([('features', FeatureUnion([('text', Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()])),
       ('length', Pipeline([('checkthings', FunctionTransformer( fun1, validate=False))])) ])),('clf', LogisticRegression())]) </code>
```

I have imported `fun1.py` in `__init__.py`. When I'm loading pickle in `__init__.py`. Got below error in visual studio :

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'checkthings' on main' from '/usr/lib/azure-functions-core-tools/workers/python/worker.py'

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: How did you import `fun1.py`? What does `fun1.py` do? Just load the pickle? Why not load the pickle in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @evilSnobu  Same error with  __init__.py as well

Comment: @shwetanayak Please provide your structure or directory of your azure function.And you init.py code. Without that,we can't repro your issue.

Comment: Azure_functions
  |- HttpTrigger
  | |- __init.py__
  | |- fun1.py
  |- pickleFile
  |- sub3

Comment: [wat](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/173/576/Wat8.jpg?1315930535)